# Animating Values in UILable IOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation

i want to display values 1-10 repeatedly in UILable with animation user should be able to see the fluctuation of the values slowly how can i achieve this functionality ?

Comment: https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use :**

```
var timer : NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "change_label", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


func change_label()

{

count = count+1
label.text = String(format: "%d",count)

}
```